# Variable going up when not supposed to

Tags: ios, swift

I have this app where pressing a button makes a score go up by one until you get above 50, then button presses add 2 to the score. But the problem is, every button press changes the level by one. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// OUTLETS

@IBOutlet weak var score: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var levelLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    add()
}


// VARIABLES

var scoreVar = 0
let levelUpAt = [10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000]
var currentLevel = 1
var toAdd = 1

// FUNCTIONS

// Below code adds to the score

func add() {
    if (scoreVar - 1 < levelUpAt[currentLevel - 1] && levelUpAt.indices.contains(currentLevel)) { // Complicated math-y if statment THANK YOU RASHWAN L (STACK OVERFLOW) FOR HELPING
        currentLevel += 1 // Change level
        toAdd += 1 // Change toAdd
        levelLabel.text = "Level \(currentLevel)" // Change the level label
        scoreVar += toAdd // Adds toAdd (level amount) to scoreVar
        score.text = "\(scoreVar)"; // Updates text to match
    } else {
        scoreVar += toAdd // Adds toAdd (level amount) to scoreVar
        score.text = "\(scoreVar)"; // Updates text to match
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're only adding 1, so why would it go up by 2? Am I missing something?

Comment: The point is to have "levels", so when it reaches 10, 50, 100, etc... it adds one to `toAdd` which means that when `scoreVar += toAdd` is ran, and `toAdd` is 2, it would add 2 to `scoreVar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `if` condition is supposed to run the `else` code and vice versa. And the first value to compare is `scoreVar` rather than `scoreVar - 1`.

```
func add() {
    if (scoreVar < levelUpAt[currentLevel - 1] && levelUpAt.indices.contains(currentLevel)) { // Complicated math-y if statment THANK YOU RASHWAN L (STACK OVERFLOW) FOR HELPING
        scoreVar += toAdd // Adds toAdd (level amount) to scoreVar
        score.text = "\(scoreVar)"; // Updates text to match
    } else {
        currentLevel += 1 // Change level
        toAdd += 1 // Change toAdd
        levelLabel.text = "Level \(currentLevel)" // Change the level label
        scoreVar += toAdd // Adds toAdd (level amount) to scoreVar
        score.text = "\(scoreVar)"; // Updates text to match
    }
}
```